# Рекурсивно обойти массив и сравнить значения с другим масивом

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3]
const b = [4, 5, [1, 2, [3]], 4]


function isCompare(a, b) {
    const rez = {}
    b.forEach( i => {
         rez[i] = Array.isArray(i) ? isCompare(a, i) : a === i
    })
    return rez
}

a.forEach(i => {
   console.log(isCompare(i, b))
})
```

сейчас у меня получается объекты, не могу понять как сделать

1 === 1 rtue
1 === 2 false

Comment: Что такое  "1 === 1 rtue"?

Comment: @Igor  нужно сравнить элементы один за одним.  И если нашлось то выводить true. не нашлось выводить false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 6];
const b = [4, 5, [1, 2, [3]], 4];


function isCompare(a, b) {
  let rez = false;
  b.forEach(i => {
    if (Array.isArray(i)) {
      if (isCompare(a, i))
        rez = true;
    } else if (a === i) {
      rez = true;
    }
  });
  return rez;
}

a.forEach(i => {
  console.log(i, isCompare(i, b));
});
```

Comment: вроде как оно, мне кажется что для моей задачи нужно возвращать все true и все false.

Comment: Задача изначально применять стили в vue js
сравнивания два массива.
Если нашлось то true не нашлось false

Comment: @dpi Я не понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать. Попробуйте еще раз.

Comment: спасибо вроде должно сработать